# Which quasi-symplectic groupoids are symplectic groupoids?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

A *quasi-symplectic groupoid*, introduced by P. Xu in [1], consists of a Lie groupoid $\Gamma \rightrightarrows P$ together with a two-form $\omega$ on $\Gamma$ and a three-form $\Omega$ on $P$ satisfying some compatibility and non-degenerateness assumptions. Quasi-symplectic groupoids include, in particular, Weinstein's notion of *symplectic groupoids* [2] when $\omega$ is non-degenerate and $\Omega = 0$.

I've heard people make the following claim:

**Claim.** *A symplectic groupoid is equivalent to a quasi-symplectic groupoid $(\Gamma \rightrightarrows P, \omega, \Omega)$ with $\Omega = 0$.*

The implication $(\Rightarrow)$ is immediate. But I don't see why $(\Leftarrow)$ should be true, and this claim doesn't seem to appear in [1]. Specifically, I don't see why $\omega$ should be non-degenerate, i.e. a symplectic form.

**Question.** *Is the above claim true? If not, what are examples of quasi-symplectic groupoids with $\Omega = 0$ but $\omega$ not symplectic?*

## **References**

[1] Xu, P.: *Momentum maps and Morita equivalence.* J. Differential Geom. 67 (2004), no. 2, 289–333.

[2] Weinstein, A.: *Symplectic groupoids and Poisson manifolds.* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 16 (1987), no. 1, 101–104.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t true, take any integration of a non-twisted Dirac structure which is not Poisson and that is quasi-symplectic but non symplectic with $\Omega=0$.